# Prove that set is bounded but has no max/min

Tags: real-analysis

Okay so I'm reading through a proof in my text book and I dont understand one of the steps.

We are proving that the set $(0,2)$ is bounded and has neither a max or min.

We start by knowing that $0$ is a lower bound and $2$ is an upper bound.

Then to see that it has no max we suppose to the contrary that $s$ is the max.
so $s$ must be contained in the set. Thus $$0 < s < 2.$$

I understand all of this, but then the next part of the proof says.

$$0< s < (2+s)/2 < 2$$

Now I understand this would make a contradiction. But I dont understand where
$(2+s)/2$ came from and why would it be greater than $s$.

If anyone could explain this step I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: $\frac{s+2}{2}$ is the middle of the segment $[s,2]$. You could take anything between $s$ and $2$ to find a contradiction but the middle is kind of the first thing you think of.

Answer (score 1):

Since $s<2$ we have $\frac{s}{2} <1$ and thus 
$$\frac{2+s}{2} = \frac{2}{2} + \frac{s}{2} = 1 + \frac{s}{2} > \frac{s}{2} + \frac{s}{2} = s.$$
The choice of $(2+s)/2$ is just one between many other but makes sense since it is the average between $2$ and $s<2$ and thus is smaller than $2$ but bigger than $s$. Note that you could have taken $s+\dfrac{2-s}{n}$ instead, for any $n\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The author of the proof had to find something in $(0,2)$ which was greater than $s$. If I were to do this, I would think of the point halfway between $s$ and $2$, which is $$s+\frac{2-s}{2}=\frac{2s}{2}+\frac{2-s}{2}=\frac{s+2}{2}.$$ It looks like the author did the same thing. An intuitive reason that $(s+2)/2$ is greater than $s$ is that it is the same as $s/2+1$. Since $s<2$, $s/2<1$, so $s=s/2+s/2<s/2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{ 2+s}{2 }=1+\frac{s }{ 2}$

As $s$ is less than 2, half of $s$ must be less than 1. The rest of the result follows.